# How to call controller function from javascript generated button in Rails 4 app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I have integrated Stripe.js in my rails app. The app produces "Pay with Card" button. I would like to know how can I call a controller function for calling Stripe APIs for receiving payment.

show.html.erb:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="btn-group pull-right" role="group" aria-label="..." style="margin-top:10px;">
            <%= link_to 'Back to Products', products_path, class: "btn btn-default btn-info" %>
    <%= button_to 'Pay with Card',
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
      data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
      data-description="A month's subscription"
      data-amount= "<%= @shopping_cart.total*100 %>"
      data-locale="auto"></script> %>
      <!--
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-success">
      <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>
      &nbsp;Checkout
    </button> -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

shopping_carts_controller.rb

```
def checkout
  @shopping_cart.process_payment stripe_params
  redirect_to products_path
  flash[:notice] = "Succefully made payment."
end
```

How can I call the **checkout** method?

Comment: I'm not an expert about it, but here there is the official documentation about [Using Checkout and Rails](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails). It is an example, may be it can help you

Comment: Stripe.js is used on the frontend only. You can use it to tokenize the person's card. Then embed the token into your form and use Stripe's API to charge their card and complete their process. Read the [Checkout tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/tutorial) and watch the [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charging a payment in stripe is done by the following steps

1) Getting the card details from the user

2) Submitting the card details to stripe

3) Stripe returns you a token

4) Use the stripe token for charging the user through stripe [charge API](https://stripe.com/docs/charges)

This can be the view for getting the card details from the user

```
<%= form_tag charge_amount_path do %>
  <article>
    <% if flash[:error].present? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <label class="amount">
      <span>Amount: $5.00</span>
    </label>
  </article>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
  data-key="some-key"
  data-description="A month's subscription"
  data-amount="500"
  data-locale="auto"></script>
<% end %>
```

When a user submits this form, stripe returns you stripe token, you can use this token to create a charge.

Have a controller method, this will be the method that will be called after submitting the form

```
def charge_amount
charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
                 :amount => 100,
                 :card => params[:stripeToken],
                 :description => "blah-blah,
                 :currency => 'usd'
                 })
end
```

the params to this method from stripe will be like

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rhYPiRCDLQJ4F9/B09TKgiyS11YGvP34hI5/Bi9n2nB9BbiBQXAMZWxdwkjVEkiy5+PJaKMnqraWSeu+a0Fn8Q==", "stripeToken"=>"tok_198sjvLeNQnnrmxRqgbTq12n", "stripeTokenType"=>"card", "stripeEmail"=>"vcjhewv@gmail.com"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure that your Checkout HTML snippet is inside a `<form>` tag with the `action` set to the URL of your `shopping_carts_controller`.